# Help with のに construction in a sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-に, particle-の

The sentence is

> 現代ほど自分の主体性、価値観を築き上げる**のに**難しい時代はないのである。

If I understand correctly, the sentence can be simplified to

> 現代ほど難しい時代はない (There is no time period as difficult as now)

The entire sentence tells you that the difficult thing is building one's own independence and values, but I don't understand how the のに is supposed to fit grammatically in there. My best guess is that the middle part is somehow an adverb modifying 難しい.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This のに means "to" or "in order to".

The の nominalizes the verb 築き上げる.

～～に means "to do ~~" or "for doing ~~".

You are right; The whole middle part modifies 難しい.

"There has never been a more difficult time than the present time for building one's own identity and sense of values."

Comment: what is the difference between ~するために and ~するのに?